# How to get unique RocketChat push token from its MongoDB using gotify?

Tags: mongodb, wsl-2

https://github.com/immanuelfodor/rocketchat-push-gateway
what values should I use here instead of username, to get the token?

- sudo service mongodb start
- mongo
- use rocketchat

> *switched to db rocketchat*

- db.getCollection("users").find({username:"USERNAME"}, {_id:1})

> *{ "_id" : "RanD0m-UsERid" }*

- db.getCollection("_raix_push_app_tokens").find({userId:"RanD0m-UsERid"}, {_id:0, token:1});

> *{ "token" : { "gcm" : "vERy-l0nG-rAnd0M-PuSH-tOKen" } }*

- exit

**any help?**